# ffmpeg progress is freezing frames when scene change

Tags: ffmpeg, camera, rtsp, ip-camera

I'm capturing data from IP camera with RTSP protocol with ffmpeg with command:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -progress /media/kamip/stats.txt -i rtsp://192.168.1.220:554/live/h264/ch0 
-c:v copy -c:a copy -strict 1 -map 0 -f segment -strftime 1 
-segment_time 1800 /media/kamip/cam_%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S.mkv
```

I'm using this for 5 cameras. One is different type and it is in different location.
Because ffmpeg does not support reconnect I'm writing status to /media/kamip/stats.txt file. In another script I'm parsing this output and every 30 seconds I'm checking if frame number changed, if yes - it is ok, if not, I'm restarting above command.

The problem is only in the night. When is quite dark and suddenly lights on, for example when car is parking, the /media/kamip/stats.txt is showing the same frame number, so my script is recognizing this as a lost connection (video freeze)

I tried "-strict 1" option and I think it is better (one false alarm per day instead of 10 per day), so I think this may be related to ffmpeg, not camera/video source, especially because the video is fine even frame number reported by ffmpeg is still the same. Also VLC does not have this kind of problem (but I cannot use it currently for this camera)

I found that ffmpeg has build-in scene change detector, but it should works only when encoding video (I'm using "copy" option for audio and video)?

I'm thinking about different way of analyzing the video capturing, but this "-progress" in ffmpeg should works fine - and it is working fine for other cameras for few years).

I also do not see any errors, 
when I encoded one cutted file with "-loglevel debug" I saw only information like below:

```
[libx264 @ 0x25d77a0] scene cut at 174 Icost:2049115 Pcost:2006553 
ratio:0.0208 bias:0.1387 gop:54 (imb:3186 pmb:168)
```

ffmpeg in latest version

`ffmpeg version 3.3.3-1ubuntu1~16.04.york0 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609`

any help will be appreciated

Comment: That scene change msg is related to the encoder estimating whether it's cheaper to continue without a new IDR frame or not. Need to see a snippet from the progress file starting from just before the freeze to just after it.

Comment: thanks for explanation.
I will collect this output, as I said, now with "-strict 1" is much much better.